# getting parameter value from nested routes

Tags: ember.js

I have my router set like :

```
this.resource('analytics', {path: '/analytics'}, function(){
    this.resource('analyticsRuns', {path: ':exerciseRunId/analyticsRuns'},function(){
        this.resource('analyticsRun',{path: ':runId'});
    });
});
```

I jump to 'analyticsRuns' route using :

```
this.transitionToRoute('analyticsRuns',{"exerciseRunId":this.get('selectedExerciseRun.id')});
```

And my AnalyticsRunsIndexRoute is defined as :

```
AS.AnalyticsRunsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model : function(params) {
    var store = this.get('store');
     //console.log(params); //returns empty object
    //var exerciseRunId = AS.Analytics.get('exerciseRunId');
    exerciseRunId = 577;
    if(!(exerciseRunId)){
        this.transitionTo('analytics');
    }

    store.find('analyticsRun',{'exerciseRunId':exerciseRunId});
    return store.filter('analyticsRun', function(analyticRun){
        return analyticRun.get('exerciseRunId') == exerciseRunId;
    });


},
setupController : function(controller,model){
    this._super(controller,model);
    this.controllerFor('analysisTemplates').set('model',controller.get('store').find('analysisTemplate'));
}
```

});

I was wondering if I could access ":exerciseRunId" value in the AnalyticsRunsIndexRoute. Currently there isnothing set when I check the params arguments passed to this routes' model. On refresh however, the parameter becomes available to the AnalyticsRunRoute but **only on refresh**. So do I have to play with stateManagement to get the parameter value? or is there simpler way to access it. Thanks.

**SOLUTION :**

Again lots of thanks to Jeremy for walking through this. Here is how I have set up things now :

I defied routes like :

```
AS.AnalyticsRunsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model : function(params) {
    return params;
}
});


AS.AnalyticsRunsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model : function(params) {
    var parentModel = this.modelFor('analyticsRuns');
    var exerciseRunId = AS.Analytics.get('exerciseRunId')||parentModel.exerciseRunId;
    var store = this.get('store');

    if(!(exerciseRunId)){
        this.transitionTo('analytics');
    }

    store.find('analyticsRun',{'exerciseRunId':exerciseRunId});
    return store.filter('analyticsRun', function(analyticRun){
        return analyticRun.get('exerciseRunId') == exerciseRunId;
    });

},
setupController : function(controller,model){
    this._super(controller,model);
    this.controllerFor('analysisTemplates').set('model',controller.get('store').find('analysisTemplate'));
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling `transitionToRoute` you should be passing a live object.

```
this.transitionToRoute('analyticsRuns',this.get('selectedExerciseRun'));
```

When you transition from route to route the `model` hook is skipped so it's important that you pass live objects either in `transitionToRoute` or in a `link-to`.

[UPDATE] in response to a comment:

If `selectedExcerciseRun` is not a live object, then you'd need to instantiate a live object before transitioning.  Something like this :

```
var runId = this.get('selectedExerciseRun.id');
var promise = store.find('analyticsRun',{'exerciseRunId':runId});
promise.then(function(analyticsRun){
  this.transitionToRoute('analyticsRun',analyticsRun);
});
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks for the reply. To give you more context on the problem, selectedExerciseRun is not child object id, its just a filter criteria I have to use( for reg. in posts->post ember example what post_id is here is not selectedExerciseRun.Id). So after the change you suggested, the url looks like analytics/[object Object]/analytics.

Comment: See the [UPDATE] to my original answer.

Comment: Thanks for working with me on this Jeremy. The update code that you have provided is exactly what I have already used in "AnalyticsRunsIndexRoute.model". This works, but when a user refreshes the page he/she will have to be redirected to index page because 'selectedExerciseRun.id' is lost, that's the main reason I wanted id to be the part of the URL, so that even when the user refreshes the page I can show him/her list of analyticsRuns filtered by the id.

Comment: In the case of a page refresh you would use the `model` hook to set up the object.  When you transition from route to route `model` is skipped an you have to pass the model that you want to use to the `transitionToRoute` call.  When you just type in the URL directly (same as a page refresh) the `model` hook is called.  You have to account for both cases.

Comment: Agreed, in case of refresh the id from the URL is accessible to AnalyticsRunsRoute.model, but not to AnalyticsRunsIndexRoute.model. Is there a way I can pass the id from AnalyticsRunsRoute.model to AnalyticsRunsIndexRoute.model?

Comment: In `AnalyticsRunsIndexRoute` you may be able to use `this.modelFor('analyticsRuns')` to access the model itself.  You'd want to return the right thing in the `model` hook of `AnalyticsRunsRoute`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Jeremy for all the help. Things are working perfectly.

Comment: Excellent!  Glad it was of help.